# Checking Cup product structure on Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

So I want to compute the cup product structure on the torus. We are all aware of the fundamental polygon and know that we only concern ourselves with the nontrivial cup product $H^1(T) \times H^1(T) \longrightarrow H^2(T)$. If I let $a$ and $b$ be the basis elements of $H_1(T)$, then the dual basis for $H^2(T)$ is $\alpha$ and $\beta$, represented by the loops that are attached to $a$ and $b$ respectively and do not intersect any other basis element. The associated picture is [image]

If we define $\varphi$ to be the simplicial cocycle that takes the value 1 on the edges meeting $\alpha$ and 0 otherwise, and similarly $\psi$ to take the value 1 on the edges meeting $\beta$, 0 otherwise, then it is true that $\varphi \smile \psi =0$ on all 2-simplicies correct?

If so, what consequences does this result have?

Comment: If $a,b$ is basis for $H_1$ then $\alpha, \beta$, the dual basis, should be for $H^1$, not $H^2$.